# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2. Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower

Tags: .net

Hi I am using VS 2017 Commuity. When I build I am getting the this error 
I have also installed latest sdk , even I am having same issue.
Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very important and not necessarily obvious, but you'll want to **make sure that you explicitly target the 2.2.1xx version when running Visual Studio 2017 as the build versions differ between Visual Studio 2017 and 2019**:

- **Visual Studio 2019** - 2.2.2xx
- **Visual Studio 2017** - 2.2.1xx

It's very likely that you installed the latest version, but not necessarily the one with support for Visual Studio 2017. You can [find the appropriate version for 2017/2019 from the .NET Core Download page here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) that demonstrates the distinction between the two SDKs and which version of Visual Studio is supported for each:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Version]

Comment: Hi now for other projects it is giving me below error 
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower,

Comment: I don’t believe that Visual Studio 2017 has rolling out of the box that supports .NET Core 3.x. It’s _possible_ to use it in 2017 if you have 2019 installed with some workarounds, but if you are planning to .NET Core 3.x, you should consider just installing and using 2019.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following fixed the issue:

Find out the latest SDK installed by issue the following command in CMD:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Then in your project's global.json file, update the version to the latest version found from previous command:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.302"
  }
}
```